# AT+CMGL="ALL" command return only OK

Tags: sms, gsm, at-command, modem

Manufacturer: huawei

Model: E3533

Revision: 22.318.27.00.00

IMEI: 353934033009021

+GCAP: +CGSM,+DS,+ES

AT+CMGS command work well.

```
OK
AT+CMGS="99667788"

> test sms
+CMGS: 45

OK

AT+CMGL="ALL"

OK
AT+CPMS="SM"

+CPMS: 0,40,0,40,0,40

OK
AT+CPMS=?

+CPMS: ("SM","ME"),("SM","ME"),("SM","ME")

OK
AT+CMGL="ALL"

OK
```

Answer (score 1):

Most common reason for returning OK would be that there are no messages stored in memory.

To check if that's the case run the reading command without setting the Preferred Storage.